# Window decoration theme doesn’t change back

Tags: 12.04, themes, ambiance

my ambiance theme is broken. when i change the radiance to ambiance theme, title bar does not turn black, but still white as Radiance title bar. how to fix it?[image: ambiance error]

Comment: Does this still appear after log out, log in?

Comment: That title Bar Border depends on **Window Theme**, change it through Ubuntu tweak.

Comment: You should report this as a bug against gnome-control-center.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following.

Install gnome-tweak-tool by typing in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Now after it has been installed you can run it by typing

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

This should pop up window where on left side-panel there is option "Theme" Here you can set option "Window theme" to Ambiance and option "GTK+ theme" to Ambiance as well.
 This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

For **Ambiance Theme** :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
```

For **Radiance Theme** :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Radiance'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I noticed that it started to occur when I installed a KDE application from the software center, in my case it was [Subtitle Composer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subcomposer/).

When I uninstalled it, the problem was solved.

Comment: I don’t really think that it’s related…

Comment: Don't know how it's related, but it was also in my case the reason. I'll look if there's a bug filed already.

Comment: Bug is reporded here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/light-themes/+bug/993275